# Jquery validator is not un-highlighting "chosen" select box

Tags: jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

I am using Chosen with jquery valodation.
you can see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/hfdBF/9/
if you click submit, you see that the validation is working for combo and input.

if you put one letter in the input box you will get an alert that the letter un-highlighted, as it suppose to be.
**BUT**, if you choose in the select box a value, it wont be alert as un-highlighted.

do you have any idea how to get that to work?

```
$(function() {

var $form = $("#form1");

$(".chzn-select").chosen({no_results_text: "No results matched"});
$form.validate({
    errorLabelContainer: $("#form1 div.error"),
    wrapper: 'div',
});

var settings = $.data($form[0], 'validator').settings;
settings.ignore += ':not(.chzn-done)';
settings.unhighlight= function(el){
   alert(el.name + " hit unhighlight")        
}
```

});​​

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do the validation manually. You can bind a function to the `change` event handler that will check if the specific select is valid. This will also clear the error if the select is valid.

```
$('.chzn-select').change(function () {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the jQuery validation manually:

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen().change(function () {
    var value = $('#UserCompanyIds').val(); // the select element
    if (value != "") {
        $('.field-validation-error').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('data-valmsg-for') == 'UserCompanyIds') {
                $(this).html("");
                $(this).removeClass("field-validation-error").addClass("field-validation-valid");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I hope this helps!